# Joining two dataframes to create an artificial dataset

Tags: python, numpy

```
def _simulate_Wks(self, X: pd.DataFrame, K: int, n_iterations: int) -> [list, list]:
    
    cat = X[[3,4,5,6,7]]
    cont = X[[0,1,2,8,9,10,11]]

    Z_prime = np.zeros(X.shape)

    for col in cat:
        Z_prime[:,col] = np.random.randint(low=np.min(cat[:,col]), high=np.max(cat[:,col]), size=cat.shape[0])
    for col in cont:
        Z_prime[:,col] = np.random.uniform(low=np.min(cont[:,col]), high=np.max(cont[:,col]), size=cont.shape[0])

    print(Z_prime)

    simulated_Wks = []     

    for i in range(n_iterations):
        
        sampled_X = Z_prime

        Wks_star = self._calculate_Wks(K=K, X=sampled_X)
        simulated_Wks.append(Wks_star)  

    sim_Wks = np.array(simulated_Wks)
    return sim_Wks
```

How can I generate `Z_prime` as being an artificial data-set? `Z_prime` contains values from the discrete (continuous) uniform distribution for categorical (continuous) features (which I hard-coded).

Comment: You're overwriting `cat` and `cont` for each pass through the rows.  Assuming `X` is 2-D, `len(X)` gives you the number of rows, not the number of columns.  What were you expecting `cat` and `cont` to contain?

Comment: Columns from the dataframe X. I need to make a reference distribution and create an artificial data-set. But I need to make a distinction between categorical and continuous features (I hard-coded this).

Comment: If `X` is a dataframe, then your `X[:, [1,2,8,9,10]]` doesn't work.  Were you expecting that to return all the rows for those 5 columns by position?  You can use `X.loc` to do that.  Given that, `X_prime_cat` and `X_prime_cont` will have a subset of the columns.  But what do you want `cat` and `cont` to be?

Comment: Indeed, I wanted to select all the rows for those columns. Random integers from the discrete (continuous) uniform distribution for cat (cont)

Comment: What's `X`?  What errors, or wrong intermediate values?  Are `cat` and `cond` what you want before you try `concatenate`. Don't just write a big block of code and hope it runs.  Test the intermediate pieces.  The whole won't be right if the individual steps aren't.

Comment: X is a numpy array with said number of columns. And I tried printing statements in-between, but I cant get Z_prime have the same number of columns as X (and same number of rows).

Comment: So, is your goal to create an array that is the same SHAPE as X, but where all of the elements are random values within the same bounds as X?  Remember you can't mix integers and floats in a single array.

Comment: Same shape as X. Z_prime is a random data set, where we make a distinction between continuous and discrete features in X.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those intermediate arrays, and indeed they won't be particularly helpful, assuming you want the columns to be interleaved in the same order as the original.

This produces an array with the values you asked for, I believe:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randint(0,50,(20,11))
X_prime = X

cat = [1,2,8,9,10]
cont = [0,3,4,5,6,7]

Z_prime = np.zeros(X.shape)
for col in cat:
    Z_prime[:,col] = np.random.randint(low=np.min(X[:,col]), high=np.max(X[:,col]), size=X.shape[0])
for col in cont:
    Z_prime[:,col] = np.random.uniform(low=np.min(X[:,col]), high=np.max(X[:,col]), size=X.shape[0])

print(Z_prime)
```

Output:

```
[[ 4.939638    8.         33.          6.06462632 29.34803376 27.92047673
  10.10907069 45.26071181 37.         34.         40.        ]
 [27.58962248  6.         37.         37.13471058 46.72725805 21.4282369
  39.35005473 16.08329763 40.         38.         10.        ]
 [35.05757352 14.         26.         39.07555817 29.80102443 12.57649644
  35.86069164 47.78790148 12.         11.         40.        ]
 [22.08677496 30.          4.         16.8086066   9.44826919 38.93000123
  35.39630508 20.954704   22.          2.          8.        ]
 [23.73564517 24.         11.         13.44406199 45.65689637 43.90891735
  23.63212734 22.48692891  5.         33.         30.        ]
 [33.70795657 32.         29.         47.6598066  27.65806364 43.07126968
   7.78273694 41.03914817  5.         25.         35.        ]
 [21.93462027 42.         27.         32.97683542 14.82010876 21.18449914
  19.13962883 42.59547862 34.          6.         34.        ]
 [10.75974571 40.         17.         22.13315452 29.06890015  9.12119008
  44.634315   41.13814525 20.         17.         24.        ]
 [ 5.58219042 41.         32.         45.66144365  3.26794523 21.74679317
  43.93397764 20.537597    7.         23.          7.        ]
 [ 2.80288277 13.          9.         43.00648324 25.8418341  42.99789302
  13.6064614  41.55250455 43.         22.         29.        ]
 [19.02350055 38.         34.         36.11615068 16.95271812 29.0093509
   8.77225362  2.25397079 45.          7.         46.        ]
 [ 4.26870036 23.          3.         44.71218094 29.38466236 40.57681454
  15.9364613   2.30036409 30.          4.          9.        ]
 [34.78900513  6.         28.         42.58560791 35.67444186 17.53246451
   9.05995079  3.89850696  4.         22.         42.        ]
 [38.58772118 22.         17.         30.44193758 39.52956127 15.84244933
  29.09113352 22.14571376 42.          4.         28.        ]
 [24.47055993 27.         36.         38.67598599 12.06930315 30.34116524
  19.61116091 16.02624312  9.         22.         12.        ]
 [34.57653156 33.         30.         19.59014599 11.38882781 44.94414761
   7.2274945  21.58703101 41.         18.         28.        ]
 [31.0677403  32.         29.         14.51909232  6.71566188 14.30741017
  43.07708398 13.93551836 32.         38.         37.        ]
 [25.87035468  9.         43.         17.70409586 22.95970004 16.5385711
  38.96364134 31.35512652 39.         11.         29.        ]
 [38.45347072 15.         37.         42.52780401  4.59910299 17.08431454
  21.37944371  5.96820414 15.         43.         12.        ]
 [24.64579903 37.         18.         20.67133629 15.61432415 32.48991493
  31.78827919  3.28247892 42.         25.          5.        ]]
```

Comment: Didn't work yet, please see updated question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "didn't work".  What didn't work?

Comment: I need to create an artificial data set as in the function in the question, values generated from the uniform distribution or discrete uniform distribution.

Comment: Isn't that what I have done?  Each column here is a uniform random set within the min/max bounds of the corresponding column of X.  If that's not what you want, then you need to describe your need more precisely.